# Is there a baby Hello World example using BIGstack?

Tags: untagged

Intel and the Broad Institute have developed [BIGstack](https://github.com/Intel-HLS/BIGstack), described in this Broad-Intel Genomics stack [whitepaper](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/accelerate-genomics-research-with-the-broad-intel-genomics-stack-paper.pdf).

Eventually I would love to perform a variant calling on BIGstack, but it isn't clear how to run a “simple” example of BIGstack on Xeon with Altera FPGA.

Since I have my own old Altera DE2 FPGA board and I would like to run the simplest possible toy example which is possible to run on my old Altera DE2 board. Is it possible to use my Altera DE2 to run something simple on top of BIGstack?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but if you are going for FPGA analysis, have you checked [Nvidia Parabricks](https://docs.nvidia.com/clara/) Pipelines? Maybe your FPGA board would work with it.